# To show image and title on UIButton in swift

Tags: swift, uibutton

In my UIButton i want to show both the image and text. when i am adding the following code, only the image is showing but not the text. Can anyone help me to resolve the issue?

```
  override func layoutSubviews() {
           super.layoutSubviews()

           guard imageView != nil else {
            return
           }
        
        
        imageView?.frame.size.width = 25
        imageView?.frame.size.height = 25
        imageEdgeInsets.left = 0
        
        titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 25, bottom: 5, right: 0)
```

[image]

In the image 4 buttons are there. But here only the images are showing, not the text.

**2- when i am trying the following code the output is**

```
imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: (bounds.width - 25), bottom: 5, right: 0)
                   titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 0, bottom: 5, right: (imageView?.frame.width)!)
```

[image]

But here i want the image should be on left side and the text will be on right side

Comment: Do you want to replace image and text position in standart buton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subclass the `UIButton` and override `imageRect(forContentRect`, `titleRect(forContentRect` and `intrinsicContentSize` to get the desired effect

```
class MyButton: UIButton {
    var titleFont: UIFont! = nil
    var textSize: CGFloat = 0

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.titleFont = titleLabel?.font ?? .none
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        self.titleFont = titleLabel?.font ?? .none
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        CGSize(width: textSize + 40, height: 30) 
        //why height is 30? You want your imageView to be of height 25 and want top and bottom insets to be 5 each so 25 + 5 + 5 = 30
        //Why textSize + 40? You want your button to take appropriate size of text + 5 left inset of image + 25 of imageView + 5 left inset of title + 5 right inset of title
    }

    override func imageRect(forContentRect contentRect: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect(x: 5, y: 2.5, width: 25, height: 25)
        //why x is 5 because you want your image to have left inset of 5
        //why y is 2.5 ? Your button height is 30, image height is 25 so (30 - 25) / 2 = 2.5
    }

    override func titleRect(forContentRect contentRect: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        if let string = self.title(for: .normal) {
            textSize = string.widthOfString(usingFont: titleLabel!.font)
            return CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 35, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: textSize + 35, height: 30))
            //same explanation why x is 35 ? 5 (left inset of image) + 25 (image width) + 5 (left inset of text) = 35
        }
        return CGRect.zero
    }
}

extension String {
    func widthOfString(usingFont font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let fontAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font]
        let size = self.size(withAttributes: fontAttributes)
        return size.width
    }
}
```

**How to use it?**

Use it just like normal `UIButton` here is how I would use it in code

```
        let myButton = MyButton()
        myButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        myButton.setImage(.checkmark, for: .normal)
        myButton.setTitle("Checked", for: .normal)
        myButton.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)

        self.view.addSubview(myButton)
        myButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([myButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
                                     myButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 50)])
```

**Output:**

[image]

Though it seems like x and y coordinates are kind of hardcoded, they are not, they are relative values and will work with any kind of text (as long as button image width and height is 25)

[image]